# If $1 - \alpha$ is of order $\mathcal{O}(\delta)$ with $\alpha\in(0,1)$, what order is $\alpha$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, numerical-methods, approximation

If $1 - \alpha$ is of order $\mathcal{O}(\delta)$, with $\alpha\in(0, 1)$ what can I say about $\alpha$? Is it of order $\mathcal{O}(\delta)$ too?

Comment: In what limit of $\delta$? Is it $\delta \to 0$? If so then $\alpha \to 1$ so less precisely you can say $\alpha=\mathcal{O}(1)$. Of course more precisely you can say $\alpha=1+\mathcal{O}(\delta)$.

Comment: Yes I mean $\delta\to0$, thank you!